# How to send elements of data from a file to separate input boxes?

Tags: php

I have a set of 5 input boxes within a form, the first 4 are text and the  last is a selector:

```
     <div type="input">
    <div>
      <label>First Name </label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Last Name </label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Student ID </label>
      <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Tuition </label>
      <input type="text" name="tuition" id="tuition"> <br>
    </div>
  <div>
    <label>Payment Method </label>
    <select name="selection" id="selection">
        <option value="credit">Credit</option>
        <option value="debit">Debit</option>
        <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I also have a function that is grabbing a set of data from another .php file called rangen.php when the button #rand is clicked and it should be populating the data into the inputs above. The data thus far is successfully being grabbed and placed into "data" in the format:

```
{"firstname":"Ying","lastname":"Lee","tuition":3571,"studentid":"034078741","method":"Debit"}
```

however it is not filling in the form.

```
  $("#rand").click(
      function()
      {
        $.get("rangen.php",
        {},
        function(data)
        {
          $("#firstname").html(data{"mykey":"firstname"});
          $("#lastname").html(data{"mykey":"lastname"}); 
          $("#studentid").html(data{"mykey":"firstname"});
          $("#tuition").html(data{"mykey":"lastname"}); 
          $("#selection").html(data{"mykey":"method"});
        },);
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify to [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) the format of the output in the 3rd argument, like "json". Then, you get an object, and you could get properties like this. Finally, you should use `val()` instead of `html()` to fill inputs.

```
$("#rand").click(
    function()
    {
      $.get("rangen.php",
      {},
      function(data)
      {
        $("#firstname").val(data.firstname);
        $("#lastname").val(data.lastname); 
        $("#studentid").val(data.firstname);
        $("#tuition").val(data.lastname); 

        /* 
        // comparing with text
        var opts = jQuery("#selection")[0].options;
        for (var i=0;i<opts.length;i++) {
          if (opts[i].text == data.method) {
            jQuery("#selection")[0].selectedIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        */

        // Thanks to @Samir for the following: 
        // comparing with value:
        $("#selection").val(data.method.toLowerCase());

      },
      'json'); // set JSON datatype
    }
);
```

Comment: This works well, except it doesn't work for the final drop down selection window  input        $("#selection").val(data.method);

Comment: @Peter you're right! It's because you have to set the selected index. I'll update my anwser.

Comment: No still not working. The drop down categories in the form are Credit, Debit. The data is formatted {"firstname":"Ying","lastname":"Lee","tuition":3571,"studentid":"034078741","method":"Debit"}

Comment: For drop down, try this `$("#selection").val(data.method.toLowerCase());`

Comment: @Samir Thanks a lot ! I've forget this the first time :)

Comment: No worries. It happens sometimes :)